# Python Regex: How to match sub string of words

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'd like to create regex to match if they're substring of commands.

Example: configure terminal

Match if have at least: conf t

I tried to use : `r'conf(igure)?\s*t(erminal)?'`
but it matched something like "conf  txxxxx" as well.
also, it's not matched "config t"

my questions is I'd like to create that match something like these.

Match:
config ter
configu term
conf t

not matched:
confgure tminal

if match optional, it's need to be in order.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you explain more match cases?

Comment: I had a similar question, and someone showed me this really helpful link (https://regex101.com/); you just type in the sentence and you can actually see what the regex will match as you build it, super useful.

Comment: matched : conf t  , configure tigtox , configure termi
not matched : config t , config ter

Comment: Does it *need* to be a single regex? Because you will end up with something like `conf(i(g(u(r(e)?)?)?)?)?\b` ... for every possible command. A small function, on the other hand, should be straightforward to use.

Comment: Can you give me example of function?
@usr2564301  actually, your regex is great. maybe I have to spit then check in each list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A regex is not a very good solution, as it is not particularly suitable for such a test, and neither is it easy configurable, maintainable, and expandable.

Better is to write a separate function that tests a single input `i` against a possible match `m` and returns `True` if

1. `len(i) >= minimum_length_required`, and
2. as much as given from `i` matches that length from `m`.

This works for single-word entries:

```
def partialMatch(entry, full, minimum):
    return len(entry) >= minimum and entry == full[:len(entry)]

>>> print (partialMatch('con', 'configure', 4))
False
>>> print (partialMatch('config', 'configure', 4))
True
>>> print (partialMatch('confiture', 'configure', 4))
False
```

but it takes more work with multi-word commands because each separate word must be checked – and, presumably, there is a long list of possible commands. However, the general idea should be something like this:

```
def validate(entry, cmd_list):
    entry = entry.split()
    if len(entry) != len(cmd_list):
        return False
    for index,word in enumerate(entry):
        if not partialMatch(word, cmd_list[index].replace('#',''), cmd_list[index].find('#')):
            return False
    return True
```

where `cmd_list` contains a list of allowed entries and a `#` character matches the position of the minimum entry text. So you can do

```
>>> print (validate ('conf', ['conf#igure', 't#erminal']))
False
>>> print (validate ('conf t', ['conf#igure', 't#erminal']))
True
>>> print (validate ('configure t', ['conf#igure', 't#erminal']))
True
>> print (validate ('conf #', ['conf#igure', 't#erminal']))
False
```

(Of course you typically would not store the valid commands inside this call itself but in a longer list, and loop over it to find a valid command.)

Comment: Thank you for great idea! Never thought of this

Answer (score 0):

Here is Example

```
s="conf fxxx "
if not s.find('conf t'):
    print('yes')
else:
    print('no')
```

Answer (score 0):

Just elaborating @usr2564301 comment here,

`import re
pattern = r'conf(i(g(u(r(e)?)?)?)?)?\st(e(r(m(i((n(a(l)?)?)?))?)?)?)?'
text='config t'
print(re.match(pattern, text))`